# Save uploaded image to S3 with Django

Tags: python, django, amazon-s3, boto

I'm attempting to save an image to S3 using boto. It does save a file, but it doesn't appear to save it correctly. If I try to open the file in S3, it just shows a broken image icon. Here's the code I'm using:

```
# Get and verify the file
file = request.FILES['file']
try:
    img = Image.open(file)
except:
    return api.error(400)

# Determine a filename
filename = file.name

# Upload to AWS and register
s3 = boto.connect_s3(aws_access_key_id=settings.AWS_KEY_ID,
                aws_secret_access_key=settings.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY)
bucket = s3.get_bucket(settings.AWS_BUCKET)
f = bucket.new_key(filename)
f.set_contents_from_file(file)
```

I've also tried replacing the last  line with:

```
f.set_contents_from_string(file.read())
```

But that didn't work either. Is there something obvious that I'm missing here? I'm aware django-storages has a boto backend, but because of complexity with this model, **I do not want to use forms with django-storages.**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use [django-storages](https://django-storages.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) which uses `boto` internally.

You can either swap the default `FileSystemStorage`, or create a new storage instance and manually save files. Based on your code example I guess you really want to go with the first option.

Please consider using django's `Form` instead of directly accessing the request.

Comment: There's actually very complex logic that I'm going to be using, which is why I opted to just forego forms and storages here. This seems like it should be very trivial to do even without them.

Comment: @LukeSapan you don't need to use forms, to use the storage. Just initialize your storage and use `save`. I must advice against using boto directly if not needed.

Comment: BTW: if this is about image compression use [django-stdimage](https://github.com/codingjoe/django-stdimage)

Comment: Okay, I'll look into using django-storages directly. And unfortunately it isn't, it's more about saving multiple types of file URLs into the column, not necessarily all stored in S3.

Comment: Just as a matter of curiousity, do you have any ideas why the above code doesn't work?

Answer (score 14):

Incase you don't want to go for django-storages and just want to upload few files to s3 rather then all the files then below is the code:

```
import boto3
file = request.FILES['upload']
s3 = boto3.resource('s3', aws_access_key_id=settings.AWS_ACCESS_KEY, aws_secret_access_key=settings.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY)
bucket = s3.Bucket('bucket-name')
bucket.put_object(Key=filename, Body=file)
```