# Problem uploading images to S3 Bucket from Django App

Tags: python, django, amazon-s3, boto3

My problem is that images stored in media folder are not transferring to S3 Bucket. I tested with other file from request and the file did transfer, so I assume settings.py must be OK.

From views.py ->

This works:

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    imageFile = request.FILES['images']
    upload = Upload(file=imageFile)
    upload.save()
    image_url = upload.file.url
    print(image_url)
```

This does not work:

```
for i in os.listdir(folder):
        f = os.path.join(conf_settings.MEDIA_ROOT,company, i)
        upload = Upload(file=f)
        upload.save()
```

> No error but it just does not work.

This also does not work:

```
for i in os.listdir(folder):
    with open(os.path.join(folder, i)) as f:
        upload = Upload(file=f)
        upload.save()
```

```
>The error I am getting is:
>
>Exception Value:   
>'_io.TextIOWrapper' object has no attribute '_committed'
>
>at                 upload.save()
```

This is my storage_backend.py

```
from django.conf import settings
from storages.backends.s3boto3 import S3Boto3Storage



class MediaStorage(S3Boto3Storage):
    location = 'media'
    default_acl = 'public-read'
    file_overwrite = True
```

This is my model.py

```
class Upload(models.Model):

    uploaded_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    file = models.FileField()
```

I am uploading a .ZIP file with images. Unzipping it and saving them to media folder, then I want to upload from media folder to S3 Bucket. This operation fails.

The file in request.FILES is the Zip file, which I am using to test that all settings.py for AWS should be correct because it does transfer correctly.

I believe my issue has to do with the way I am reading the file and passing it.

Answer (score 0):

So after many hours....this actually worked. Although the transfer is a bit slow, im sure there must be a better way.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/53260957/11116189

Comment: If you think the post is a duplicate please give it a flag, not an answer.