# How do I set up django on heroku for direct to s3 file uploads

Tags: python, django, amazon-s3, heroku

There doesn’t seem to be any tutorials online about django direct to s3 on heroku. All tutorials are either flask or rails. I would like to know is there a tutorial or simple method for django?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Save uploaded image to S3 with Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29035857/save-uploaded-image-to-s3-with-django)

Answer (score 0):

Actually ended up using Javascript AWS SDK. Check out my answer here:
[How can I allow large file uploads on Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73089545/how-can-i-allow-large-file-uploads-on-django/73154644#73154644)